# Trouble connecting to a Wi-Fi with given user and password

Tags: internet

So I'm at this hotel, and I have trouble connecting to their Fortinet wi-fi. They gave me the user and password, but I gotta be redirected to a web page, and when I open Firefox or Ubuntu's browser it won't load anything.

But the funny thing is when I connect on my Android device, I receive a notification with that log in page.

I am sorry if I asked the question here, but I have trouble on my Ubuntu machine so I think it's Ubuntu related.

Comment: Have you tried copying the URL from the page your android device goes to into the browser on your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: This is what I tought about too, I'll be trying doing that

Comment: @DavidFoerster it's ok blendenzo's answer helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try copying the URL from your android device browser into the browser on your Ubuntu machine, and you should be able to get to the wifi registration page for your hotel.